# Capitalization of "A" in "Dear All"

Tags: orthography, capitalization, email

At my work place, whenever an e-mail is sent to more then one person, it starts with "Dear All" or "Dear all". Should the letter "A" be capitalized in "All" as it is not a proper noun? Would it be wrong not to capitalize it

Comment: In the question: [**Is it appropriate to use the salutation “Dear All” in a work email?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292/is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-salutation-dear-all-in-a-work-email?rq=1) you'll find that  the answers have *all* written with and without a capital letter. IMO it's a question of aesthetics, not grammar. If you think the capital letter lends a more elegant tone to the email, there is no rule that stops you. If you want to be a stickler for accuracy/appropriateness then you could argue that *all* is not a proper noun, and as such should not be capitalized.

Comment: related: [*Usage of 'Dear All'*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32199/usage-of-dear-all) also [*How do you greet multiple recipients in an e-mail?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/how-do-you-greet-multiple-recipients-in-an-e-mail) and finally [*Usage of “Hi” and “hi” in a letter/mail*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7673/usage-of-hi-and-hi-in-a-letter-mail)

Answer (score 3):

The rule I've always followed is: When a word is used in place of a proper noun, capitalize.  In this case, you are directly addressing "All," so I would capitalize: "Dear All."

Answer (score 1):

As when we write essay title we write this way like My Home, My Village.
Starting a letter this way is rather informal, so there are no absolute rules. I'd favour Dear All.

You might also consider things like Hello Everyone, To All Tenants, Please Note.
so no problem if it starts with Dear All or Dear all.