# Capitalizing the first letter of each word in letter greeting

Tags: orthography, capitalization

I have searched for an answer on the site, but all the questions I have found (*e.g.* [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261297/capitalization-of-a-in-dear-all)) seem to be less general.

Assuming that I'm writing a cover letter to join a team working on a project called, say, 'Purple Frog', I'm not sure whether I should write

```
Dear Purple Frog Project Team,
...
```

or

```
Dear Purple Frog project team,
...
```

What are the rules that I should follow here?

Comment: It depends. Are they called 'Purple Frog', 'Purple Frog Project', or 'Purple Frog Project Team'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about the greeting of a letter with regard to capitalization. You should capitalize words where they are part of a proper noun, just like everywhere else in the letter.

If the team's name is "Purple Frog Project Team" then that is the capitalization you should use. If it is a team that just happens to work on a project called "Purple Frog" then you should write "Purple Frog project team".